# How to make 2 identical switch buttons work one the same page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2 toggle buttons with different ID's, but they work together although I set them both different classes. When clicking on one of them - the second one is working also. I guess, I missed a class or something - perhaps there is a way to make element like this more independent/reusable?

[**jsbin**](https://jsbin.com/lititac/edit?html,css,output)

Html:

```
<div id="switch-gender-1" >
    <div class="switch-1" style="border-radius:25px;">
        <input type="radio" class="switch-input-1" name="view" value="male_1" id="male_1" checked>
        <label for="male_1" class="switch-label-1 switch-label-off-1 male-1">
            <i class="fa fa-mars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <label>
                Homme
            </label>
        </label>
        <input type="radio" class="switch-input-1" name="view" value="female_1" id="female_1">
        <label for="female_1" class="switch-label-1 switch-label-on-1 female-1">
            <label>
                Femme
            </label> <i class="fa fa-venus" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
        <span class="switch-selection-1"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="switch-gender-2" >
    <div class="switch-2" style="border-radius:25px;">
        <input type="radio" class="switch-input-2" name="view" value="male_2" id="male_2" checked>
        <label for="male_2" class="switch-label-2 switch-label-off-2 male">
            <i class="fa fa-mars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <label>
                Homme
            </label>
        </label>
        <input type="radio" class="switch-input-2" name="view" value="female_2" id="female_2">
        <label for="female_2" class="switch-label-2 switch-label-on-2 female">
            <label>
                Femme
            </label> <i class="fa fa-venus" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
        <span class="switch-selection"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sass:

```
#switch-gender-1{
  .switch-1 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    width: 161px;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #d1d1d1;
    .switch-label-1{
      .fa {
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-top: 7px;
      }&.male-1 {
         float: left;
       }
      &.female-1 {
        float: right;
      }
      &.male-1 .fa {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 12px;
        color: #333333;
      }
      &.female-1 .fa {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 15px;
        color: #333333;
      }
      &.male-1 label {
        left: 37px;
        top: -23px;
      }
      &.female-1 label {
        right: 35px;
        top: 4px;
      }

    }

  }
  .switch-label-1 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    float: left;
    width: 58px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    & label {
      display: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      position: relative;
    }
    &:active {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  }

  .switch-label-off-1 {
    padding-left: 2px;
  }
  .switch-input-1 {
    display: none;
    &:checked + .switch-label-1 {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
      text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
      -webkit-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
      -moz-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
      -o-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
      transition: 0.15s ease-out;
      -webkit-transition-property: color, text-shadow;
      -moz-transition-property: color, text-shadow;
      -ms-transition-property: color, text-shadow;
      -o-transition-property: color, text-shadow;
      transition-property: color, text-shadow;
    }
    &:checked + .switch-label-1 label {
      display: block;
    }
    &:checked + .switch-label-on-1 ~ .switch-selection-1 {
      left: 46px;
      /* Note: left: 50%; doesn't transition in WebKit */
    }
    &:checked + .switch-label-1.female-1 .fa {
      position: relative;
      top: -30px;
    }
    &:checked + .switch-label-1 .fa {
      color: rgb(73, 200, 193);
    }
  }

  .switch-selection-1 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -4px;
    left: -3px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    width: 113px;
    height: 42px;
    /* border-radius: 3px; */
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
    -o-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
    transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 6px 18px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 6px 18px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
    border-radius: 25px;
  }

}
/*--------------------------*/

#switch-gender-2{
  .switch-2 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    width: 161px;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #d1d1d1;
    .switch-label-2{
      .fa {
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-top: 7px;
      }&.male {
         float: left;
       }
      &.female {
        float: right;
      }
      &.male .fa {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 12px;
        color: #333333;
      }
      &.female .fa {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 15px;
        color: #333333;
      }
      &.male label {
        left: 37px;
        top: -23px;
      }
      &.female label {
        right: 35px;
        top: 4px;
      }

    }

  }
  .switch-label-2 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    float: left;
    width: 58px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    & label {
      display: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      position: relative;
    }
    &:active {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  }

  .switch-label-off-2 {
    padding-left: 2px;
  }
  .switch-input-2 {
    display: none;
    &:checked + .switch-label-2 {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
      text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
      -webkit-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
      -moz-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
      -o-transition: 0.15s ease-out;
      transition: 0.15s ease-out;
      -webkit-transition-property: color, text-shadow;
      -moz-transition-property: color, text-shadow;
      -ms-transition-property: color, text-shadow;
      -o-transition-property: color, text-shadow;
      transition-property: color, text-shadow;
    }
    &:checked + .switch-label-2 label {
      display: block;
    }
    &:checked + .switch-label-on-2 ~ .switch-selection {
      left: 46px;
      /* Note: left: 50%; doesn't transition in WebKit */
    }
    &:checked + .switch-label-2.female .fa {
      position: relative;
      top: -30px;
    }
    &:checked + .switch-label-2 .fa {
      color: rgb(73, 200, 193);
    }
  }

  .switch-selection {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -4px;
    left: -3px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    width: 113px;
    height: 42px;
    /* border-radius: 3px; */
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
    -o-transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
    transition: left 0.15s ease-out;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 6px 18px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 6px 18px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
    border-radius: 25px;
  }

}
```

Comment: Should users be able to be both male and female?

Comment: If you want then to be able to use both, which seems to be the case, have you tried using checkbox instead?

Comment: @Brainfeeder    Hahahah.... well no... but it's a page defines  children's of users...so ....

Comment: @AndréSousa Thanks - but i have to follow that specific design....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Radio buttons shared a single value for the named input. So as your two input share the same name (aka "view") they share the same value.

You should have "view" and "view2" for input names.